# How to select Max date that is valid?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date, type-conversion

I have a date as varchar (dont ask why). I need to select Max(date). However, date can be faulty, like 2034-34-34. I would like to select max date that is valid and not greater than today. It's t-sql.

I tried:

```
create table #tmp (
  dt varchar(10)
)

insert into #tmp values ('2022-02-15'),('2034-34-34')
select max(dt) from #tmp
having isdate(max(dt))=1 and max(dt)<=current_timestamp
```

As return I get nothing.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have for now:

```
create table #tmp (
 dt varchar(20)
)

insert into #tmp values ('2022-02-15'),('2034-34-34'),('2022-03-14'),(null)
select top 1 dt from #tmp
where isdate(dt)=1
order by dt desc
```

The result:
2022-03-14

**Update**:
Thank you all, I have a solution from your answers:

```
create table #tmp (
 dt varchar(20)
)

insert into #tmp values 
    ('2023-02-15'),
    ('2034-34-34'),
    ('2022-03-14'),
    ('2000-01-01'),
    (null),
    ('04/14/2030')

select 
  max(try_cast(dt as date)) as maxValidDate
from 
  #tmp
where 
  try_cast(dt as date ) is not null and try_cast(dt as date) <= current_timestamp
```

Returns 2022-03-14

Comment: You can BTW simplify your where clause to: `where try_cast(dt as date) <= current_timestamp`. If try_cast evaluates to null, any comparison with that will never evaluate to true

Answer (score 2):

Your `HAVING` clause was the issue in your post's example query. `HAVING` is usually used to filter with aggregates *within* a group of values. Also your were evaluating if the max value was a date in the order of events in that `HAVING` clause, rather than filtering out non-date values first, then getting the max, such as your answer now does.

Another version of the query to get you the same answer would just be:

```
create table #tmp (
 dt varchar(20)
)

insert into #tmp values ('2022-02-15'),('2034-34-34'),('2022-03-14')
select max(convert(date, dt)) from #tmp
where isdate(dt)=1
```

This *could potentially* be faster by eliminating the use of an `ORDER BY` clause, especially if you indexed your table by the field `dt` like so `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TMP_DT ON #tmp (dt)`. This would store the data already sorted by the `dt` column then, which is beneficial if you were to have repeated runs of the `SELECT` query. One could verify the differences by looking at the execution plans, and time & I/O statistics.

Comment: Could you edit your answer so the condition "and dt<=current_timestamp" also apply? I get The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Note that ISDATE() returns 1 specifically if the string is convertible to datetime. If you want it as date, datetime2 or smalldate, then it gets it potentially wrong. Consider using TRY_CAST() instead, which allow you to specify the desired type.

Answer (score 2):

May or may not be an issue, but neither `max(dt)` nor `top 1 ... order by dt desc` will return correct result if someone stored a valid date as example: '04/15/2030'

```
create table #tmp (
  dt varchar(10)
);

insert into #tmp values ('2022-02-15'),('2034-34-34'),('04/15/2030');

select max(dt) from #tmp
where isdate(dt)=1;

2022-02-15
```

Reason is that dt is compared as a string. You can cast valid "dates" to dates, before comparing:

```
select max(cast(dt as date)) from #tmp
where isdate(dt)=1;

2030-04-15
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3764c33a7a6532a55622e5c64d5a192)